# Apache POI not removing comment from cell in the Excel sheet

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi, cell

I want to remove comment and styles in an Excel file. The below method is working, but does not remove the comment. I think `cell.removeCellComment();` is not working.

How can I fix that issue?

```
 private List<AssetContent> removeBgColorAndComments(final List<AssetContent> contents) throws IOException {
    for (AssetContent content : contents) {
      try (final FileInputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(content.getTemporaryFile());
           final XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(inputStream);
           final ByteArrayOutputStream byteStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream()) {
        final CellStyle style = workbook.createCellStyle();
        style.setFillBackgroundColor(IndexedColors.WHITE.getIndex());
        for (int sheetIndex = 0; sheetIndex < workbook.getNumberOfSheets(); ++sheetIndex) {
          for (Row row : workbook.getSheetAt(sheetIndex)) {
            Iterator<Cell> cellIterator = row.cellIterator();
            while (cellIterator.hasNext()) {
              Cell cell = cellIterator.next();
              cell.setCellStyle(style);
              cell.removeCellComment();

            }
          }
        }

        workbook.write(byteStream);
        content.setTemporaryFile(AssetContentUtils.createAssetContentTempFile(new ByteArrayInputStream(byteStream.toByteArray())));
        content.setContentLength(byteStream.size());
      }
    }

    return contents;
  }
```

Comment: Please don't add those colons back in. Normally tags should not be added in the title, but in this case using it as a normal part of a sentence works. Adding the colons is unnecessary, and is actually an indication that it doesn't belong in the title at all.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution for that issue. Looking through the POI javadocs, since cellIterator() does not return blank cells, that's why some commented blank cells not removed in the in the excel sheet.For this I want to get all cells, no matter if they exist or not, then the iterator isn't. Instead, I need to manually fetch the appropriate cells, likely with a missing cell policy.

```
final XSSFSheet sheetAt = workbook.getSheetAt(sheetIndex);
for(Row row : sheetAt) {
    for(int cn=0; cn<row.getLastCellNum(); cn++) {
        Cell cell = row.getCell(cn, Row.MissingCellPolicy.CREATE_NULL_AS_BLANK);
        cell.setCellStyle(style);
        cell.removeCellComment();
    }
}
```